# Heroku rake command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I'm trying to push my Rails app to Heroku, and I'm at the point where I'm trying to create/migrate the database, but I cannot get the rake command to run.  Here's the message I'm getting:

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.2439
bash: rake: command not found
```

I spent a lot of time getting Postgres set up on my local machine, and it's working fine (was able to run rake commands without issue, and the app is running locally), but I don't know why I'm getting this error when I try to migrate the heroku database.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Figured it out.  Turns out I had an error when I tried to deploy the app to Heroku, so it was never deployed.  I didn't realize this because I was trying to push a branch that was not the "master" branch to heroku, thinking it would be fine.  I wasn't getting any errors on that push, but that's because heroku won't try to deploy anything other than the "master" branch.  Once I pushed the "master" branch, I got a bunch of pre-compile errors.  Once those were cleaned up, I the app was deployed properly and I was able to run the rake commands.

**Long story short, make sure your app successfully deployed before trying to run rake commands.**